# Error creating bean with name 'com.budthapa.StatusTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'statusUpdateDao'

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, junit4

I'm trying to test the save operation using JUnit on StatusUpdate class but got the following error that says error creating bean on test class. I'm learning spring boot.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.budthapa.StatusTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'statusUpdateDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.budthapa.domain.StatusUpdateDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:386)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.budthapa.domain.StatusUpdateDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1486)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585)
... 28 common frames omitted
```

**StatusTest.java**

```
package com.budthapa;
import javax.transaction.Transactional;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.web.WebAppConfiguration;

import com.budthapa.domain.StatusUpdate;
import com.budthapa.domain.StatusUpdateDao;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@Transactional
public class StatusTest {

@Autowired
private StatusUpdateDao statusUpdateDao;

@Test
public void testSave(){
    StatusUpdate status=new StatusUpdate("This is a test status update");
    statusUpdateDao.save(status);
    /*
    assertNotNull("Non-null",status.getId());
    assertNotNull("Non-null",status.getAdded());

    StatusUpdate retrieve=statusUpdateDao.findOne(status.getId());
    assertEquals("Matching status update", status, retrieve);
    */
    }   
}
```

**StatusUpdateDao.java**

```
package com.budthapa.domain;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface StatusUpdateDao extends CrudRepository<StatusUpdate, Long>{

}
```

This is the entity class

**StatusUpdate**

```
package com.budthapa.domain;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;

@Entity
@Table(name="status_update")
public class StatusUpdate {
    @Id
    @Column(name="status_id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="status")
    private String text;

    @Column(name="added_date")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date added;

    public StatusUpdate(){}

    @PrePersist
    private void onCreate(){
        if(added==null){
            added=new Date();
        }
    }

    public StatusUpdate(String text){
        this.text=text;
    }

    public StatusUpdate(String text, Date added){
        this.text=text;
        this.added=added;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }
    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    public Date getAdded() {
        return added;
    }
    public void setAdded(Date added) {
        this.added = added;
    }

}
```

**SocialNetworkApplication.java**

```
package com.budthapa;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.domain.EntityScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@EntityScan
public class SocialNetworkApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SocialNetworkApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `@EnableJpaRepositories("com.budthapa.domain")` in SocialNetworkApplication.class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.budthapa.domain")
@EntityScan("com.budthapa.domain")
public class SocialNetworkApplication {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SocialNetworkApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: try adding @SpringBootTest in your test class.